# Barracuda WAF on Service Fabric

Tags: firewall, azure-service-fabric

is there any way to configure Barracuda WAF or any other WAF tool for Service Fabric? I've been trying to do this using the documentation for AppService (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-web-application-firewall/ ) but i can get it to work.

Any suggestion? I could find any documentation about it.

Thanks

Comment: Show code from what you've tried and any error messages received

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try configuring an Azure Application gateway, but as far as I'm aware, you need to do it when creating your cluster using an ARM template.